# I am trying to make a list of the first 10 squared numbers with python. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying to print a list of squares of 1-10. I am expecting to add these values to a list and then print out the list. The expected values of the list should be [1, 4, 9, 16 ....]

This is my interpretation of the code to get those results:

```
squares = list(range(1, 11))
for x in squares: 
    square = x ** 2
    squares.append(square)  
print(squares)
```

When I hit run, I don't receive an error. It simply fails to print/execute.
Please, I would appreciate your help with this. Thank you.

Comment: it's simple: `print([x**2 for x in range(1,10)])`

Comment: @OleksandrLykhonosov Amazing, thank you very much. That works! I am just wondering if you know what was wrong with the logic of my code.

Comment: @OleksandrLykhonosov: End of the `range` should be `11`, not `10`, to make it include `10`.

Comment: @MonteCarlow Be sure to post the **exact** code to reproduce a problem.  Code before my edit was `squares. Append(square)` which is a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong in your code is that you keep appending a value to the list you are already iterating through. Your program never exit the `for loop`.
Do like the following:

```
numbers = list(range(1,11))
squares = []
for x in numbers:
    squares.append(x**2)
print(squares)
```

**UPDATE**
We can achieve same result reducing the number of code line using list `list comprehension` [read more](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension). The `range()` function returns `tuple` [read more](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) which could be iterated same way lists do. Try the following:

```
squares = [x**2 for x in range(1,11)]
print(squares)
```

Comment: As a side-note: There's *no* reason to convert the `range` to a `list` here. `numbers = range(1, 11)` would work equally well, and (slightly) faster. Or just get rid of `numbers` entirely, and make the loop `for x in range(1, 11):` (assuming you don't collapse it all down to a listcomp).

Comment: Your program definitely accomplishes what I was trying to do. Thank you very much for taking the time to help a noob. could you elaborate more on my program continuously iterating and never exiting the for loop? @F T

Comment: Yeah you are right. But he seems a starter and I thought it is better to go his way. With list comprehension, this code takes not more than two lines

Comment: @MonteCarlow The variable `squres` initially is a list of numbers `1 - 10` with the length of 10. At the first iteration, the program squares the first value which is 1 and append it back to the same list making its length 11. At the end of 10th iteration, your list's length grows to 20. The list keeps growing with out end because you keep appending square of squares to the list. That is why your program prints nothing as it never finish iterating through the for loop.

Comment: @ShadowRanger That makes sense.

Comment: @f-t It finally clicked. I was growing the list at the same time as I was trying to iterate through it and perform the squaring arithmetic. I'm sorry I don't know how to correctly refer to your username with spaces :( but I appreciate your help with this.